# Ionic2 minimum iOS and Android versions

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Ionic2 (beta) supports Android 4.4 and up, but I understand with CrossWalk it can support earlier versions (but which?)https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-v2-latest-version-is-not-working-with-android-4-2-2/50611

I haven't managed to find the minimum iOS version - that would also be most welcome.  Can I run iOS 7 (like current Ionic) ?

All the best

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the notes cordova 4.0 supports iOS 8.

**Requirements and Support**

Apple® tools required to build iOS applications only run on the OS X operating system on Intel-based Macs. Xcode® 6.0 (the minimum required version) runs only on OS X version 10.9 (Mavericks) or greater, and includes the iOS 8 SDK (Software Development Kit). `To submit apps to the Apple App Store℠ requires the latest versions of the Apple tools.`

You can test many of the Cordova features using the iOS simulator installed with the iOS SDK and Xcode, but you need an actual device to fully test all of the app's device features before submitting to the App Store. `The device must have at least iOS 8 installed, the minimum iOS version supported as of Cordova 4.0.0.` Supported devices include iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, iPhone 5C, iPhone 5S, iPhone 6, iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6S, iPhone 6S Plus, iPhone SE, iPad 2, iPad 3, iPad 4, iPad Air, iPad Air 2, iPad Pro, iPad Mini, iPad Mini 2, iPad Mini 3, iPod Touch 5th gen and iPod Touch 6th gen or later.

**Ref:** https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/

Comment: Is the version that Ionic 2+ supports directly correlated to the version of Cordova it supports?  Seems like there would be some front-end issues in iPhone 4S with Ionic 2+ even though the plugins and features are supported in Cordova.

Answer (score 2):

Another reference is [this ionic docs link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/overview/#browser-support), there is also ionic v2 mentioned.

**Ionic 1**
Ionic V1 is focused on building native/hybrid mobile apps rather than mobile websites.

As such, our browser support tends to be whatever Web View API is available to native apps on a given platform. For Ionic 1x, that means UIWebView for iOS 7+, and Android 4.1 and up. We recommend using Crosswalk to improve performance on older devices.

**Ionic 2**
Ionic 2 is focused on building both native/hybrid apps through Cordova, as well as adding the ability for Progressive Web Apps and Electron .

The following OSs and browsers are supported:

iOS 8+
Windows 10 Universal App
Android 4.4+
Support can be pushed back to 4.1 if Crosswalk is used with Cordova